# What is the fastest way to multiply different numbers by consecutive numbers?

Tags: python, math

My main goal is to make this code faster, like converting it to an equation or something else

This code multiplies the digits of the number system with 'n' and the 
digits size of 'l', and provided that there is no digit less than the digit to the left

For example:
If n = 3 and l = 2
The result will be 25 which is the product of multiplying the cells of these lists :

[1, 1]

[1, 2]

[1, 3]

[2, 2]

[2, 3]

[3, 3]

```
def plus(num_list,n,index):

    if (num_list[0] == n and index == 0): return 0

    if num_list[index] < n:

        num_list[index]+=1
        num_list = num_list[:index+1]+[num_list[index] for x in range((len(num_list)-1)-index)]

    else:
        return plus(num_list,n,index-1)

    return num_list

while True:
    n = int(input('n = '))
    l = int(input('l = '))
    rez = 0
    num_list = [1 for x in range(l)]
    while num_list:
        print(num_list)
        m = 1
        for i in num_list:
            m*=i
        rez+= m
        num_list = plus(num_list,n,l-1)

    print(rez)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the code a bit to print out 10 values for each l from 1 to 10 gives:

```
l=1: 1,3,6,10,15,21,28,36,45,55,
l=2: 1,7,25,65,140,266,462,750,1155,1705,
l=3: 1,15,90,350,1050,2646,5880,11880,22275,39325,
l=4: 1,31,301,1701,6951,22827,63987,159027,359502,752752,
l=5: 1,63,966,7770,42525,179487,627396,1899612,5135130,12662650,
l=6: 1,127,3025,34105,246730,1323652,5715424,20912320,67128490,193754990,
l=7: 1,255,9330,145750,1379400,9321312,49329280,216627840,820784250,2758334150,
l=8: 1,511,28501,611501,7508501,63436373,408741333,2141764053,9528822303,37112163803,
l=9: 1,1023,86526,2532530,40075035,420693273,3281882604,20415995028,106175395755,477297033785,
l=10: 1,2047,261625,10391745,210766920,2734926558,25708104786,189036065010,1144614626805,5917584964655,
```

These numbers can be looked up in the [online encyclopedia of integer sequences](https://oeis.org/). Which gives sequences such as [A001296](https://oeis.org/A001296), [A001297](https://oeis.org/A001297) and [A001298](https://oeis.org/A001298). They have a description "Sterling numbers of the second kind S(n+l, n)". Which are referenced in [Mathworld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/StirlingNumberoftheSecondKind.html) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind).

Formulas for the first few l's:

```
l==1: n*(1+n)/2
l==2: n*(1+n)*(2+n)*(1+3*n)/24
l==3: n^2 (n + 1)^2 (n + 2) (n + 3) / 48
l==4: (n+4)*(n+3)*(n+2)*(n+1)*n *(15*n^3 + 30*n^2 + 5*n - 2)/5760
```

PS: [Sympy](https://docs.sympy.org), Python's symbolic math library, has a function [`stirling`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/functions/combinatorial.html#stirling) to calculate its values. It only works with fixed integers, not with symbolic variables.

```py
from sympy.functions.combinatorial.numbers import stirling

n = int(input('n = '))
l = int(input('l = '))
print(stirling(n+l, l))

for l in range(1, 11):
    print([stirling(n+l,n) for n in range(1,21)])
```

The formula at Wikipedia can also be written using more basic sympy functions.

```py
def s(n, k):
    return Sum(((-1) ** (k - i)) * binomial(k, i) * i ** n / factorial(k), (i, 0, k)).doit()
```